# I'm getting an error trying to pull content from a page with my scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x

The issue is, the class of the HTML that I'm trying to pull from has a dash in it. Python is unable to read that dash correctly, so it's not able to pull the data that I need.

How do I write it so that Python can correctly read the dash and pull my data?

```
print(page_content.bid-price)  # Here's the dash "bid-price"
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're seeing something like:

```
AttributeError: 'Xxx' object has no attribute 'bid'
```

That's because `bid-price` isn't a valid [identifier](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers), so the code is being interpreted as a subtraction:

```
page_content.bid - price
```

When you have an attribute with a name that isn't a valid identifier, you can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
print(getattr(page_content, "bid-price"))
```